# Как переопределить метод?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

Как переопределить метод при использовании `QUiLoader().load("name.ui")`

```
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
class form():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
    def initUI(self):
        self.ui=QUiLoader ().load ("form.ui")
        self.ui.paintEvent=self.func #При таком переопределении метод paintEvent не срабатывает
        self.ui.show()
    def func(self,qp):
        print('tut ya')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication (sys.argv)
    wform = form ()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

Код формы **form.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>120</x>
     <y>110</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>250</x>
     <y>140</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `form.ui` и лучше объясните, что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Comment: в form.ui обычный QWidget с 2мя кнопками, при изменении размеров формы что то же вызывается, но в функцию func программа не заходит.

Comment: Опубликуйте модуль `form.ui`. Что вы хотите увидеть при изменении размеров формы?

Comment: ваш вопрос еще актуален ? Если да, опубликуйте модуль `form.ui.` и объясните лучше, что вы хотите сделать и что получается не так. Если вопрос решен - опубликуйте ваше решение или закройте вопрос.

Comment: Я хотел понять как переопределяются методы класса , если я использую QUiLoader ().load(). И возможно ли это?

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать? Зачем вы хотите переопределить метод `paintEvent`. ? Почему вы считаете, что `При таком переопределении метод paintEvent не срабатывает` ? Почему у класса `class Form()` нет наследника ?

Comment: uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)  вы этим кодом загрузили содержимое в Form() ?

Comment: QUiLoader().load("form.ui",self) я когда так пишу выходит ошибка: AttributeError: 'Form' object has no attribute 'pushButton'

Comment: Поэтому в class Form() нету наследника, так как он вроде не нужен. Используя self.ui = QUiLoader().load("form.ui") форму я через wform.ui.show() отображаю. И ко всем обьектам form.ui обращаюсь через wform.ui.*******

Comment: я как то неправильно использую QUiLoader ().load ("name.ui") получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Операции рисования обычно выполняются в функции события `paintEvent()`.
Для того чтобы переопределить метод `paintEvent`
вам нужно прописать его в классе и заполнить нужным функционалом.

В PyQt5 это может выглядеть так (см.пример ниже).
Кликаем кнопку 'Click me' и наблюдаем что происходит.

```
'''
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5 import uic            #   from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class Form(QWidget):                                    # + QWidget
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
#        self.ui = QUiLoader().load("form.ui")          # PySide2
        uic.loadUi("form.ui", self)             # PyQt5 
        
        self.pushButton.setText('Click me')
        self.pushButton.setCheckable(True)  
        self.pushButton.setChecked(False)   
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.update)        
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        print('tut ya')
        
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman', 30))
        painter.drawText(100, 100, 'Hello PyQt5!')        
        
        if self.pushButton.isChecked():
            painter.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman', 15))
            painter.drawText(100, 200, "Кнопка 'Click me' нажата")          
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication (sys.argv)
    wform = Form()
    wform.show()
    sys.exit (app.exec_ ())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]